# Hibernate: preventing multiple same entries in role table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

Whenever I save a user and its role(s) to my database, it also adds an extra row in my Role table.

Each user has many roles and each role can belong to many users).

I have 3 tables in my database:

- `users` (id, username)
- `roles_users` (user_id, role_id)
- `roles` (id, role)

E.g. I have 2 roles in my `Role` table (`ROLE_ADMIN`, `ROLE_USER`), I save a user with the role `ROLE_ADMIN`, my `roles_users` table is updated, but a new row is also created in my `Role` table (I want to prevent this).

There are a couple of ways I could prevent this from happening:

1. Write a query that only updates my `user` and `roles_users` table
2. Set the role-id to the same id as the role-name (basically overwriting the row, I am doing this now)

So my question is, is there a better way to do this with hibernate?

This is my `User` model:

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String username;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "roles_users",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "role_id"})})
private Set<Role> roles;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    if (roles == null) {
        roles = new HashSet();
    }
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

This is my `Role` model:

```
@Entity(name = "roles")
public class Role {

@Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<User> users;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    if (users == null) {
        users = new HashSet();
    }
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

This is the code I use to save a user and its role:

```
    User user = new User();
    Role role = new Role();

    user.setUsername("john");
    role.setName("Admin");
    role.setId(Long.valueOf(1));
    role.getUsers().add(user);
    user.getRoles().add(role);

    userService.saveUser(user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are creating instance of role then adding user to that and then again from that user instance you are adding same role in last line hence you are having two roles object assign to this user thats why storing two enteries so remove the second last line of code adding role object again and use the following code to save user, it should work  for you-

```
User user = new User();
Role role = new Role();

user.setUsername("john");
role.setName("Admin");
role.setId(Long.valueOf(1));
role.getUsers().add(user);


userService.saveUser(user);
```

instead of above try with save method of role.

Comment: why needed to add it again, user entity already you initialized then role have collection of users and you added that by following line- role.getUsers().add(user).  Then this user entity have bidirectional relationship with role hence having the role object values so at last you just need to save that user object hence the code I gave you is correct!!

Comment: I removed my comment (I was wrong in saying that). Btw it doesnt work unfortunately, the role object is never saved.

Comment: ok, np, you can try with saving role instance too instead of user, which can save you user instance in background.

Comment: I just tried saving the role instance only, only user data is saved, no role data :(

Comment: @Id
//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)                                                     why you commented this

Comment: I was not able to update the role id manually if that line wasnt commented

Comment: that should not be a case you can update that manually too, the next record will pick the next largest id value for this key, try once by un-commenting I think this is preventing to store in Role table,

Comment: I uncommented that line of code, deleted the tables, created fresh ones and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120275/discussion-between-chetan-verma-and-richard-avalos).